# SQL | I want to compare a sum of two or more rows and then make a select statement

Tags: sql

So I have this table in MySQL:

`datec.masini`

[image]

So, a `proprietar (person unique ID)` can have one or more cars with a `valoare (value $)` and I want to show by a `SELECT` statement all the persons (`proprietar`) with cars above 190000$.
I tried this but doesn't work:

`SELECT proprietar FROM datec.masini WHERE sum(valoare)>190000`

and I want this result:

`1990724 5780623`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you describe the error or unwanted result you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT proprietar
FROM datec.masini
GROUP BY proprietar
HAVING SUM(valoare) > 190000;
```

Comment: Thank you!
The correct form is: SELECT proprietar
FROM datec.masini
GROUP BY proprietar
HAVING SUM(valoare) > 190000

Comment: Oh...I thought you wanted all people having at least one car costing 190000.  I have edited my answer to the version you actually want.